# I need help making a logo animation transparent for client to use in after effects

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency, video

I have made an animation in blender of an animated logo. I am ready to render but I don't know how to render it to where the video output is ready to be placed in after effects or other video compositing programs to where the logo can be on top of the background video layer with the logo's background being transparent. For single images I know I render in PNG with ARGB and transparent check box on.

thing is if I render out the video into images and then make them into a video, will it be able to do the transparency or do I need to do something different to get there. My client does not know blender and needs the video as a simple template for after effects or premiere pro. please help this is my first paid job lol.

Comment: Use OpenEXR as the output file format. That way you can save your scene referred information intact, plus alpha, z-depth, ID maps, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render your video two times: one normal (check transparent in the render options, the result will be black), and one using in the compositor node editor the alpha output, so to have a video file of the alpha channel. Then, in the final compositing software, you will use the alpha channel video to drive the transparency of your normal video.

[image]